# Facebook Open Graph giving error "Can't download: Could not retrieve data from URL" and status code 206

Tags: node.js, express, facebook-opengraph

This works:

> http://www.opengraph.in/?url=snakes.eric-wieser.tk/fb-og.html

But this doesn't:

> http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=snakes.eric-wieser.tk/fb-og.html

The page being scraped is [here](http://snakes.eric-wieser.tk/fb-og.html). I don't think I can make it much simpler

Facebook gives a status 206, and says it can't download any data from the page.

---

I'm using Express and Node.js, set up like this:

```
var app = express.createServer();
app.listen(8090);
app.use(express.static(__dirname, {maxAge: 60000}));
```

Why isn't it working?
What ca

Comment: Having the same problem with a page served from Amazon S3 http://media.apps.chicagotribune.com/tables/elevator-safety-inspections.html